# protractor does not load the page

Tags: protractor

I have a very basic protractor test and you can find its code [in this repository](https://github.com/salman-/Basic-Protractor).

I try to open a website using the below command:

```
console.log(".................................   Before");
browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/calc/').then(()=>{
  console.log("Page is shown!!!!");
});
console.log(".................................   After");
```

But, the problem is, when i run the code

it opens the browser, but it immediately close it.
So, it does not load the website.

**What is the problem, that prevent loading the page?**

---

Update when i run the code I have only:

```
.................................   Before
.................................   After
```

and the `Page is shown!!!!` **is never printed**

Comment: Can you edit the questions with error stack trace?

Comment: There is no error. It just opens the browser and close it.

Comment: Can you add the terminal console after running your protractor config? We can understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: my code is based on cucumber and the console just shows the report about `cucumber`. So, there is no special information. However, you have the complete code in the repository.

Comment: Ok let me clone and check it.

Comment: which protractor are you using?

Comment: i am using `"protractor": "~5.4.3",` @SergeyPleshakov

Answer (score 0):

I added a return statement to the browser.get() in the Given. It worked fine.

[image]

You should use return statement in the last step of your step definition. Usually it should be a expect.

refer the second screenshot i have displayed the title.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is you're not waiting for `browser.get()` to complete. `browser.get()` is a promise that you need to resolve first or else it will continue to the next line of code without navigating to the desired page.

Convert your function first into asynchronous by adding the `async` keyword before the function.

e.x `async function() { ... }`.

Then resolve the navigation by appending the `await` keyword before the promise. 
e.x

```
console.log(".................................   Before");
await browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/calc/').then(()=>{
  console.log("Page is shown!!!!");
});
console.log(".................................   After");
```

Then your expected results should be:

```
.................................   Before
Page is shown!!!!
.................................   After
```

Answer (score -1):

the execution is very speed that u will not be able to see it probably 
try to add this  `browser.sleep('3500')`; after your `browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/calc/');` to verify that there is a real problem.